# PHP display a variable in a variable (string)

Tags: php, variables

I have this code

```
$text = "Hello $person";
$persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo $text."<br>";
}
```

The goal is to display:

```
Hello Mike<br>
Hello Tom<br>
Hello Foo<br>
```

I thought about using {} and $$, but that doesn't seem to be ok.
What am I missing?

Comment: You could just try `echo "Hello ".$person."</br>";` instead. No need for the `$text` string then

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction: sprintf

Comment: $text = "Hello %s";
inside the loop:
echo sprintf($text,$person);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You're assigning `$text` to a string that includes `$person`, but `$person` isn't defined yet (you should be getting a `Notice: Undefined variable` message). You could define `$text` within the loop, like many other answers suggest. But your code sample might look more familiar with `sprintf`:

```
$text = "Hello %s";
$persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo sprintf($text, $person) . "<br>";
}
```

[`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) will allow you to format a string by passing a parameter to it.

Answer (score 2):

This should achieve it.

```
    $persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
      foreach ($persons as $person) {
         echo "Hello " . $person . "<br>";
      }
```

Comment: Indeed that would work, but the real variable is defined much more extensive.

Answer (score 0):

To make this simpler you could do

```
 $persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo"); 
foreach ($persons as $person)
 { echo "hello".$person."<br>";
 }
```

Or you would do

```
   $text = "Hello";
    $persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
     foreach ($persons as $person) 
    { 
    echo $text." ".$person."<br>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let be a little creative, probably not the best, but it is one liner.

```
$persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
echo vsprintf(str_repeat("Hello %s<br>", count($persons)), $persons);
```

Another one liner can be achieved with `implode`

```
echo "Hello" . implode("<br>Hello ", array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo")) . "<br>";
```

**Note** that my solution is not recommended, but it would be boring to have same answer as other people.

Comment: Even more beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just append hello using foreach the way i am doing is somehow very similar!

```
$persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
      foreach ($persons as $person) {
      echo "Hello " . $person. "<br>";// Remove text and append Hello + break tag ofcourse
      }
```

Outputs:-

> ```
> Hello Mike
> Hello Tom
> Hello Foo
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$persons = array("Mike", "Tom", "Foo");
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $text = "Hello $person";
    echo $text."<br/>";
}
```

$text is outside foreach, for that reason $person wasn't echoed